# knitr + LyX2.0.5.1: pdf generation fails

Tags: knitr, lyx

With LyX2.0.5.1 I have an error during the pdf generation.

**1st file: aab.lyx.**
LyX Error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \title. <*> aab.tex *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

The   temporary file aab.Rnw is created. With Rstudio I can open it and compile the pdf.
    The aab.tex file stops with **\title{A**

The title is "Aïkido Aviron Bayonnais".

**2nd file: bp.lyx.**
LyX pop-up:

```
 Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'exécution :   
    Rscript --verbose --no-save --no-restore "/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Resources/scripts/lyxknitr.R" "/Users/alainbret/tmp/lyx /lyx_tmpdir.EWu435/lyx_tmpbuf2/""bp.Rnw" "/Users/alainbret/tmp/lyx/lyx_tmpdir.EWu435/lyx_tmpbuf2/""bp.tex" UTF-8 "/Users/alainbret/Git/test/BloodPressure/scripts/".
```

The temporary files bp.Rnw and bp.tex are correctly created.
With Rstudio, I can produce the pdf.

The files are correctly proceeded with LyX2.0.4, R3.0.0.0, and the dev version of knitr.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two LyX bugs that may affect you: [#8504](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8504) and [#8537](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8537). Both bugs have been fixed in the development version of LyX, and the next release (2.0.6) is perhaps one month away.

You can fix #8504 by yourself following the instructions in the section "Other languages" in [this page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/lyx/). But you cannot do anything about #8537 unless you compile LyX from source. Anyway, please try to fix the first problem and see if it helps.

BTW, although it may not matter, the current release of LyX is 2.0.5.1. You can upgrade it.

Comment: I have applied the solution for #8504. All is OK now!
Thanks a lot for your help.
Congratulations for the job you are doing with "knitr".